# send terrafrom output of ressources created on aws using gitlab ci

Tags: aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, terra

I created ressources on AWS using terraform and depolyed with gitlab ci. I want to send the output of the gitlab pipeline to a lambda function already existing but I have no idea if it's possible.

br

Comment: You want to send the output to lambda through Terraform or with aws cli? Like environment variable? Or you want to invoke the lambda and pass it as input?

Comment: the output of the terraform are stocked in a file using gitlab, I want to send this file a variable to a lambda directly after I run  the gitlab ci pipeline

Comment: Can you use AWS CLI in GitLab CI to inoke the lambda and pass a json payload to it (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) using `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest` as image

Comment: Also you can expose your Lambda trough API Gateway and send a request to the endpoint created with the output of terraform.